# Microsoft word templates

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, templates

I'm looking for some advice regarding Microsoft Word. Is there a way I can create a contracts template with auto fill? For example, if I have a template contract, can I create a format/formula where I enter text and it will automatically appear in a specified field?

The fields to be input would be Name, Address, Date, Job Title and the like. I'd like to specify sections of the Word file where the same template data would be used.

Thanks

Comment: have a look on [mail merge](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Mail-merge-507b5468-f771-485d-9ef0-27857168a266), probably that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can by defining **VARIABLE**s for data you wish to reuse and using the **FIELDCODE**s to populate them using the **ASK** fieldcode

I have done this myself for several contracts, but it's not very user friendly and easily overlooked.

see [my previous answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1188615/651538) for more details and link to useful resources

If further interested I can post some sample code here.