# Setting and getting variable with Microsoft Word (no VBA)

Tags: microsoft-word, forms

I'm using a template in word with text content control and I want to access the text written.

I tried to google it but it seems I don't have the right keywords.

For instance, the beginning of my text could be :

```
Publisher : [ _____ ]
Writer : [ _____ ]
```

And I could then insert the publisher or writer name later in the text based on what the user put in the fields.

Is this possible ? (it don't have to be a content control though)

NB : the document is to be used by not-geek-at-all, and so it should not use any VBA or other 3rd party app.

Comment: have a look on custom document properties (https://wordribbon.tips.net/T007794_Inserting_Custom_Properties_with_Fields.html and https://word.tips.net/T000661_Creating_Custom_Document_Properties.html)

Comment: This is quite interesting but not what I was looking for. I clarified my post.

Comment: You can use document merging, to merge an excel sheet with a list of variables to multiple documents.

Comment: yes I thought about it, but I would like the variables to be set inside the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think bookmarks might work well in this situation.

1. First, make sure the user cannot delete your content control by selecting the control and locking it from deletion. Developer tab > Properties > check box in the Locking area > OK.

[image: Content control properties window]

2. Second, select the content control and insert a bookmark. Insert tab > Bookmark. Enter a bookmark name and click Add.
3. Within your text, add a cross reference to the bookmark. Insert tab > Cross-reference > select relevant bookmark > Insert button.

**Important note: cross-references do not immediately auto-update. I usually select all my text [Control A] and push [F9] to update.

When data is entered and the fields updated, you will have something like this:

[image: Example text with updated content control and bookmarks]

Comment: One thing though : the content won't update if the "content cannot be deleted" is checked on the cross-reference. I couldnt add the reference to the text only, so it copy-pastes the whole content control.

Answer (score 1):

This might have to do with Word Field Codes. Try the following

The Function and Shortcut Keys that manipulate fields

**Windows Keys  | What**

- F9   | Update/Refresh Selected Field
- Shift+F9 | Display/Hide Field Codes (selected field)
- Alt+F9   | Display/Hide All Field Codes (all fields in document)
- Ctrl+F9  | Create Empty Field (Insert { }Braces)

I use fields often when trying to automate forms See [Here for more info](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm)